# Import a package to a class is not recognizable in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, import, package, dependencies

I have the following class called `DeviceConsistencyCodeGenerator.java` of the directory `devices` and a part of the package : `package mylibsignal.devices;` as shown in the picture : [DeviceConsistencyCodeGenerator.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gRTLC.jpg)

I want to import this class (DevicesConsistencyCodeGenerator.java) in another class that is in another directory, which means not in the same package. The class where I want to import the package `mylibsignal.devices` is shown in the picture : [SignalServiceCipher](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaUZ7.jpg)

The problem is when I try to import the package `import mylibsignal.devices` or `import mylibsignal.devices.DeviceConsistencyCodeGenerator`, it is not recognizable. Can someone help me fix this?

Comment: Images and screenshots can be a nice addition to a post, but please make sure the post is still clear and useful without them. If you post images of code or error messages make sure you also copy and paste or type the actual code/message into the post directly. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812/5987669

Comment: @Locke there is no error, that's why I added pictures :)

Comment: It looks like those folders are in separate modules. In addition the `app` folder is not correctly configured. Go into File > Project Structure > Modules, and make sure that your java source folder (named "java" in your screenshot) is marked as such. Once that is done, it should give you better insight into the issue. `mylibsignal.devices` is not a valid package due to the current classpath, so you will need to move some stuff around. It looks like it is acctually in the package `org.wispersystems.mylibsignal.devices`.

Comment: @Locke should the class path be included in the package name?

Comment: The package inside a java file should reflect all of the packages is inside of.